# How do I fetch name.json file with reactNative locally?

Tags: json, react-native, offlineapps

> For Android application!

**Let say in our project folder we create a file name.json.**

Now I want to use the name.json file for displaying some data in our application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the file like below:

```
import nameData from 'yourPathToFile/name';
```

Now you can use it like:

```
//IF name.json have an array
nameData[0].name; // example
//If name.json have object
nameData.name; //example
```

Comment: Can I store name.json file in any root level custom folder?

Comment: You can store it in any directory that you can access from JS

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thanks